# How to convert linear recurrence to a tiling question

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, recurrence-relations

If I have some linear recurrence of form

$$f(n) = a_1f(n-1) + a_2f(n-2) + a_3f(n-3) + \cdots + a_kf(n-k)$$

How does this translate to tilings? For example the Fibonacci sequence is the same as asking how many ways you can tile a 1xn board with tiles of length 1 and 2. How does this generalize to any linear recurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... sort of.  One slight twist is needed, to account for the $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ terms.  Let us assume, for the moment, that these are all non-negative integers.

Suppose that you have $a_1$ different colors of tiles of length $1$; $a_2$ different colors of tiles of length $2$; all the way up through $a_k$ different colors of tiles of length $k$.  (Assume you have an unlimited supply of every color of every length tile.)

In how many ways can you use these tiles to cover a $1\times n$ board?

The first tile must have some size, $t$; this tile can be in any one of the $a_t$ colors we have in tiles that size.  Having placed that tile, we then have to come up with some way to tile the remaining $n-t$ spaces.  This is where we get the recurrence
$$
f(n)=a_1\,f(n-1)+a_2\,f(n-2)+\cdots+a_k\,f(n-k),
$$
as you requested.

Comment: Then, barring some very serious special cases, I don't see any way to relate this to tilings.  The entire point of the recurrence relation for these sorts of tiling problems is that you have partitioned the problem in to subcases, and you have to _sum_ the contributions by each subcase.

Comment: Good question and good answer :)